# logForm.$invalid.$setValidity what's this mean?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

https://github.com/PatrickO10/meetUp/blob/master/index.html#L73

I am new in this field and reading one code.

I can't understand `logForm.$invalid.$setValidity` here. I can't find anything about it from internet. The `setvalidity` in the internet has two perimeters but here has not.

And the `invalid` here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController has been a boolean why `setvalidity`? Why don't you use `ng-disabled="logForm.$invalid"`

Could you tell me? Thanks.

```
<div class="modal fade login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModelLabel" ng-controller="LoginCtrl as logCtrl">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header primary-color-dark-bg">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="loginModelLabel">Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body primary-bg">
                <form class="row form-horizontal" id="loginForm" ng-submit="logCtrl.login(user)" name="logForm">
                    <label for="logEmail" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 margin-top">
                        <span class="pad-right">Enter your email</span>
                        <input type="email" id="logEmail" ng-model="user.email" class="form-control" placeholder="example@krustykrab.com" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                    </label>
                    <label for="logPass" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 margin-top">
                        <span>Enter your password</span>
                        <input type="password" id="logPass" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 margin-top" ng-show="loginError">
                        <p class="invalidPass">Login Fail! {{loginErrMsg}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-xs-12 margin-top">
                        <input id="submitLogin" type="submit" value="Login" ng-disabled="logForm.$invalid.$setValidity">
                    </label>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer primary-color-dark-bg">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="submitLogin" type="submit" value="Login" 
             ng-disabled="logForm.$invalid.$setValidity">
```

You are basically saying the input to be `ng-disabled` when the form is `$invalid`. i.e, here you are setting the input to `$invalid`, which makes the input to be disabled.

Comment: Could you find some document describing about this setvalidity?

Comment: Look at this link, it provides a lot of examples of $setValidity. http://ng-learn.org/2014/03/Writing_Custom_Validations_Part4/

Comment: And this link too... http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/11/exploring-angular-1.3-validators-pipeline.html

Comment: I believe the accordingly code is https://github.com/PatrickO10/meetUp/blob/master/js/meetupEvent.js#L52-L83 Could you tell me how can I make the form invalid? I mean how to set the value of logForm.$invalid

Comment: I can see that all your example of setValidity have two perimeter, but mine here has no perimeter?

Comment: You can either pass values to it or you can do something like the link shared above by you... basically you are setting the validity of your element to valid or invalid... here the orginal author is setting it to $invalid when he knows the form is invalid.

Comment: Could you tell me the exact line where the form is set to invalid?

Comment: Why don't you use `ng-disabled="logForm.$invalid"`

Comment: I think `ng-disabled="logForm.$invalid"` is ok, but why `logForm.$invalid.$setValidity` :<

Comment: I am guessing the required attribute is playing an important role here, which is triggering the $setValidity...